# Rails: how to make update_attribute to do validatation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Model Material has three attributes: `attr_one, attr_two, attr_three`

In Material controller

```
def update 
  @material.update_attribute(:attr_one, 'Atom')
  @material.update_attribute(:attr_two, 'Sublime')
end
```

This will bypass both validations of attr_one and attr_two.
I want to bypass the validation of attr_one, but want to do validation of attr_two.
How to achieve this?

Can I do like this?

```
def update 
  @material.update_attribute(:attr_one, 'Atom')
  @material.save(validate: false)
  @material.update_attribute(:attr_two, 'Sublime')
  @material.save(validate: true)
end
```

Comment: didyou get it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) will run validations:

```
@material.update_attribute(:attr_one, 'Atom')
@material.update(:attr_two: 'Sublime')
```

> Can I do like this?
>
> ```
> @material.update_attribute(:attr_one, 'Atom')
> @material.save(validate: false)
> @material.update_attribute(:attr_two, 'Sublime')
> @material.save(validate: true)
> ```

No, running `save` on object will make no sense, since `update_attribute` and `update` will ***both already*** save the object.